# Javascript add listener or automatically add attribute to all new Image() instances

Tags: javascript

There is a 3rd party javascript that is injected that creates a new Image() after some logic to build a specific path but does not append it to the document.

```
(function(){
    {....}
    new Image().src = "some_image_path";
})();
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to get what the resulting "some_image_path" that is generated. I don't what to change it or anything, just get the value. I don't have control over that 3rd party JS and it can't be changed. I've tried using cujojs/meld but it either did nothing or got "Illegal invocation" errors.

Is there a way I can get what that src value is by either observing the Image/HTMLImageElement obj or by automatically adding an onload attribute to all Image instances to a function I have defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try loading the third party script in a closure with a self-defined `Image` constructor.

```
(function() {
  var img;
  var Image = function Image() {
    return img = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(window.Image, arguments));
  }

  // This is where the 3rd party code should be injected.
  // I'm assuming that since you're including it on your page, you know its source and trust it enough to `eval` it.
  // You won't be able to use a `<script>` tag to load it since that would execute in the global scope.
  // You'll likely need to use AJAX to fetch the script contents and pass to eval here.
  eval("new Image().src = some_image_path");

  return img;
})().src == some_image_path;
```

**EDIT**:

You can overwrite the global `Image` (and be nice and fix it afterward) instead.  Since script tags are evaluated in order, this should work.

```
<script>
  var img;
  var oldImage = Image;
  Image = function Image() {
    return img = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(oldImage, arguments));
  }
</script>

<script src="..."></script>

<script>
  // img now contains the instantiated `Image` object
  img.src; // do what you will with this

  // Clean up
  Image = oldImage;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @arcyqwerty. I can't use ajax to get the script because it violates cross domain since the script is hosted externally. Its unlikely that I would be able to have this 3rd party add the necessary headers.

Comment: @IronheadJay: updated answer. It's not as elegant, but should work with cross-domain scripts.